# Не передается по CAN значения

Tags: stm32, can

У меня проблема с передачей по CAN шине на микропроцессоре STM32f303k8t6.

Вообщем я считаю значение температуры с термопар, принимаю их процессором, все ок! значения приемлемые, дальше сигнал через процессор передается на CAN драйвер, и потом все это идет на CAN шину. Так вот, если я в буффер для CANA записываю, какие либо статичные значения типа [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То все ок (выделено 0xFF), но если я передаю туда значения считанные с термопары (centigrade1 в массиве Data[0]) то все я принимаю, какую то дичь, непонятные значения, но не те которые считываются

Comment: я бы не стал каcтовать к int

Comment: тем более приоритеты операций приведения к типу и деления посмотрите.

Comment: @eri короче по CAN шлются сообщения, ну видимо, какая-то проблема с HAL_DALAY(). Я его поставил перед HAL_CAN_TRANSMIT() и начало работать, но есть одно но! отправлется только последняя температура, а в остальных по 0!!!